# How to extract only date and time from a large logfile?

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, logfile

I'd like to extract just date and time values out of a log file.

Here are a couple of lines from the log file:

> 2022-05-22 13:51:52,689 STATUS [Thread-5] hoststate.HighwayMonitorObserverImpl.localHighwayStateChanged - Highway State Changed [LOCAL APP_HW] to FAILURE.
> 2022-05-22 13:51:54,448 STATUS [HostStateManager[0]] hoststate.HostStateManager.a - [0] high way state changes : sys1-a - [OK, OK, OK, null]->[DELAY, OK, OK, null]
> 2022-05-22 13:51:54,450 STATUS [HostStateManager[0]] hoststate.HostStateManager.a - [0] update necessary

Btw I'm trying to parse all dates from the log files into another file and I'm stuck at this moment, thanks to everyone who could help me.

Comment: how large can be the file?

Comment: you can try regular expressions with `20[0-9]{2}-[01][1-9]-[0-3][0-9] [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9],[0-9]{3}` or alike pattern

Comment: where is the code you tried?

Comment: there are several log files up to 250kb each @viveknuna

Comment: @MukulKeshari i tried a lot but i didnt achieve something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 250kb size file, you can use the below code using Regex.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

// read file
string logFile = File.ReadAllText("abc.txt");

// Use regex
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(logFile);

// print all dates
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just did it, using this commandline command:

```
grep -o "[0-9\-]* [0-9\:]*,[0-9]*" file.txt
```

Explanation:

- `[0-9\-]*` covers the date
- `[0-9\:]*` covers the time, minus the milliseconds
- `,`        makes the presence of the comma mandatory
- `,[0-9]*`  covers the milliseconds, based on the mandatory comma

You can use this as a basis for your regular expression.